# JQuery Chosen plugin + AJAX loading dynamic select

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am using the jQuery plugin chosen. It is working fine on (document).ready, but I have a button that, when clicked, uses ajax to dynamically create more select objects that I want to use the "chosen" feature. However, after adding new select element only this new element works correctly and others doesn't: if i have one select and recently added a new select javascript (getting dropdown by clicking on the select etc) works only for the last one.
Here is my JavaScript code for dynamically adding new select elements:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    alert("hello");
    var drop = document.getElementById('Select_chzn');
    var spans = drop.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    var chosen = spans.innerHTML;
    $.post('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getfield', {
        'fieldName': chosen
    },

    function (result) {
        document.getElementById('content')
            .innerHTML += result;

    });
    setTimeout(doChosen, 100);
    event.preventDefault();
});
});

function doChosen() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
}
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you mean that the selects aren't working or that the chosen style is not applied to them?

Comment: I mean that selects aren't working. Chosen style works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically select the chosen plugin , you can just trigger an liszt update then change to it . 
Example let say MyDropDown is the dropdown ID , then

```
  $('#MyDropDown').val('value you want').trigger("liszt:updated").trigger("change");
```

works for me